# What was the first film shot completely with a subjective point of view?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

What was the first full-length feature film shot completely with a subjective point of view, that is, with a subjective camera where shots simulates what a character actually sees (audience, character, and camera all "see" the same thing).

An example of what I mean is [The Russian Ark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Ark), by Sokurov, or [Cloverfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloverfield).

Answer (score 12):

[*Lady in the Lake* (1947)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0039545/trivia?tab=tr&item=tr0721602)

> The entire movie plot unfolds from lead Robert Montgomery's point of view, thus creating a rarity in film: the principal character is only seen on-screen as a reflection in mirrors and windows, and as the narrator speaking directly to the audience.

Comment: "**With the exception of a couple of times** when Montgomery (in character) addresses the audience directly, the entire film is shot from the viewpoint of the central character, Marlowe." So it's not a full length subjective camera. Could that be ok to @JuanZe or you're looking for a 100% subjective camera ?

Comment: A 100% subjective camera could be a better answer

Comment: @Advicer Montgomery is only ever seen in mirrors. I don't see how that, or addressing the audience directly, constitutes an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the movies of the "Found Footage" genre are basically full lenght subjective camera works.

By the way, I can't think a 100% POV movie before **The Blair Witch Project** (1999).

Here You can find some good lists to dig:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Found_footage_(genre)
http://horror.about.com/od/horrorthemelists/tp/povhorrormovies.htm

Comment: It's been a while but don't they pass the camera around in that movie? So we don't see 100% of the movie from the point of view of **one** character only.